# email and password remember me for login after user logged in for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

when the user login to his account and click remember me how to make the login form auto-fill the user email and password when the user come to login again so he doesn't have to fill his email and password again in react and next

Comment: That feature is from the browser, not from your website. If you store the user's password in plaintext anywhere on your platform (either backend or frontend), which you will need to do in order to auto-fill his password, then the security of your platform is nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, store user's credentials on front side (localStorage, lessionStorage and etc.) is not a good practice.

Usually "Remember me" checkboxes are used to create an `auth-cookie` with longer time life.

For example:
When user checked "Remember me", you will send post request with query params `remember=1`, server handle this, and send response with header:

```
Set-Cookie: {auth-cookie}={value}; Max-Age={one week, for example}
```

It will create a cookie in browser, which time life is one week.

In another case, if user didn't check "remember me", server responds with header like this:

```
Set-Cookie: {auth-cookie}={value}; Max-Age={one day, for example}
```

It means that user will be authorized during just one day, after it cookie will be expired, and user will logged out.

User can allow the browser to autocomplete input fields if click "Save password" after submitting the form in browser's popup.

[image]

It's browser behavior.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

You can use `localStorage`, a built-in object in JavaScript for browsers.
`localStorage` is of type `Storage`, which means that you can use it via the methods `setItem`, `getItem`, and `removeItem`.

### How to use

```js
localStorage.getItem("item1"); // null
localStorage.setItem("item2", "EntityPlantt");
localStorage.getItem("item1"); // still null
localStorage.getItem("item2"); // "EntityPlant"
localStorage.item1; // "EntityPlantt"
location.reload(true); // Reloads page
```

> **`localStorage` is persistent, so you can call it on load to fill in the form.**

### Examples

```js
onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("data")) {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.data);
    // fill out the form
  }
}
```

And, when someone fills the form, you can save the form data in `localStorage`.

```js
btn.onclick = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify({
    // Form data
  }));
  submitForm(); // The submitting of the form; your code here
}
```

Note that `localStorage` can only store strings. So you can convert them to your type.

```js
var number = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("number"));
var string = localStorage.getItem("string");
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
var array = localStorage.getItem("array").split(",");
var symbol = Symbol(localStorage.getItem("symbol"));
```

## Reference

If you want to learn more about `localStorage` (and `sessionStorage`), go to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser (better encrypted). Then, if the user doesen't refresh the localstorage you will be able to use this information to fill the form.

Comment: Even with encryption, I believe localstorage doesn't get wiped if the user password is forcibly reset, so it's less secure than just letting the browser/OS handle the password management.

Comment: @Martheen more importantly, even if it's encrypted, the decryption algorithm must exist on the client anyway. It's not much more secure than unencrypyed.